# TempData[] is not working after redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, viewbag, tempdata

I am trying to use mvc `TempData[]` to send an error message to another controller with the redirect:

Controller 1:

```
    TempData["Message"] = "A password reset email has been sent to " + user.Email +
                                     ". This link in only valid for 24 hours.";
                    return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Users", new { id = userId });
```

I then have the following helper class situated at the constructor of Controller 2:

```
public UsersController()
    {            
        NotificationHelper.GetViewDataNotifications(this);
    }
```

Here is the helper class:

```
 public static void GetViewDataNotifications(ControllerBase controller)
    {
         var message =controller.TempData["Message"] ?? "";
        controller.ViewBag.Message = message;

         var errorMessage = controller.TempData["ErrorMessage"] ?? "";
        controller.ViewBag.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;

         var infoMessage= controller.TempData["InfoMessage"] ?? "";
        controller.ViewBag.InfoMessage = infoMessage;

        var warningMessage = controller.TempData["WarningMessage"] ?? "";
        controller.ViewBag.WarningMessage = warningMessage;
    }
```

I then expect for the `ViewBag` items to be populated by the time I get to `Edit` `Action` :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
     ...
     return View();
    }
```

However in my helper class the TempData always seems to be null. What am I missing here?

Is there some factor to the `TempData[]` that I am not aware of, such as its only valid in the same controller or its only valid for a single action?

Comment: Don't call the method in the constructor. At that point the controller isn't even fully constructed yet. Properties like TempData haven't been loaded.

Comment: So should I call my helper in the action which it is needed?

Comment: @Zapnologica Yes that's correct.

Comment: OK I will try, I did this so I do-not have to duplicate the code in every action method.

Comment: You champion. Please post an answer so I can accept it. If you could additionally add a way to somehow append my helper to every/ some action methods in the controller.

Comment: There's no need for this helper anyways. Just access `TempData` directly in your view. There's no need to set the values in `ViewBag` first. All you're doing is moving the data from one dynamic storage location to another.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Now that you mention that, seems like a much smarter and simpler solution. I can just remove the view bag completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to access TempData in the controller's constructor when it's still empty. At this point the controller isn't even fully constructed yet, much less initialized.

You should extract the TempData values inside your actions. TempData is initialized at least three steps after controller construction but before authorization and model binding.

This [document](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application) describes the controller lifecycle in detail. While you can overrideone of the steps between TempData initialization (`CreateTempDataProvider`) and the actual action, there isn't much point to it.

Comment: Ya, it took me a while when first learning that even the controllers aren't instantiated until MVC decides.  I had "thought" that once they were instantiated they stuck around on the server side. Putting global vars in the controllers didn't work out too well for me personally and I'd advise anyone against that practice.  Look at the controller as the end result of routing which instantiates the models and sends the proper view back out. No more, no less.

Comment: Controllers are instantiated and disposed with each request: pretty straight-forward. Globals and static vars are a no-go because they aren't thread-safe.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Interesting that you say that. The default scaffolding in mvc 5 generates your controllers with your `EF db context` as a global and is instantiated in the controller. Then is used in each Action. Is this also incorrect?

Comment: That's not a global. It's an instance variable. A new context is instantiated and stored in that each time the Controller is instantiated, so it's thread-safe.